# Declarative pipeline Jenkins groovy.lang.MissingMethodException

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Checkout SCM : Some Git repo') 
    {
        steps {
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'refs/heads/proj_dev_branch']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'], [$class: 'WipeWorkspace']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'credId', refspec: '+refs/heads/proj_dev_branch:refs/remotes/origin/proj_dev_branch', url: 'git@REPO_URL.git']]])
        }
    }


    stage ('Some stage')
    {
        steps {
            sh "echo Something"
            sh 'cat $WORKSPACE/somedir/somefile.txt'
        }
    } 
    }

}
```

When its with Scripted syntax just works fine, but with declarative one, I am seeing below exception. Does `checkout` step needs to be wrapped differently?

> Started by GitHub push by  Running in Durability level:
>   MAX_SURVIVABILITY [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline [Pipeline] End of
>   Pipeline hudson.remoting.ProxyException:
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.Any.initialize()
>   is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap,
>   java.lang.Boolean) values: [[:], false]   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:49)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.model.Agent.getDeclarativeAgent(Agent.groovy:122)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inDeclarativeAgent(ModelInterpreter.groovy:591)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.call(ModelInterpreter.groovy:78)
>     at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)     at
>   ***cps.transform***(Native Method)

Comment: Assuming `checkout` is a global var method, you would need to contain it within a `script` block.

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard for response. No luck even with wrapping with `script` block. Not sure what's problem here, as it not pointing to specific line/step/stage. .. Per this : https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-steps  , it does mentions on : _The script step takes a block of Scripted Pipeline and executes that in the Declarative Pipeline. For most use-cases, the script step should be unnecessary in Declarative Pipelines, but it can provide a useful "escape hatch." script blocks of non-trivial size and/or complexity should be moved into Shared Libraries instead._

Comment: Script block is not necessary for `checkout`. You can use any step without script block as long as you don't need to use return values of steps and don't need control structures such as loops.

Comment: Can you show your scripted pipeline that works, for comparison?

Comment: As we know it's just few small changes for scripted pipeline with `node` replacing `pipeline` and no explicit `stages` block. Figured out the issue & i see it is due to recent `pipeline-* hpi` plugin upgrades & was not considered as corresponding`*.jpi` were taking precedence. Fixed or solved by removing non needed ones & pipeline started working without `scripts` block or any change needed per example. .. Surprisingly Jenkins didn't complained when I visited `Jenkins->Manage Jenkins -> Configure System` section (no plugin errors in red!)